# CakePHP 2.0 - beforeFilter() not run on cakeErrorController?

Tags: cakephp, exception, cakephp-2.0

I've worked with CakePHP 1.3, but this is my first foray into CakePHP 2.0 and PHP exceptions, so bear with me if my question seems wordy.

In my `AppController`'s `beforeFilter()` I set a couple of variables via `$this->set()` for use in my view template.

In my `UsersController` I have code that looks roughly like this:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
  parent::beforeFilter();
  if (userDeniedAccess()) {
    throw new ForbiddenException();
  }
}
```

where the hypothetical function `userDeniedAccess()` encapsulates my authorization checks.

This all works fine, and I get the 403 error when I expect it. However, when the exception is thrown, the view variables that were set in `AppController::beforeFilter()` are no longer set, resulting in errors from my view template. When the exception is *not* thrown, the variables are set correctly.

I can code around the missing variables if I must, but I'd really like to know what causes this behavior. Both my `UsersController` and the `CakeErrorController` extend `AppController`. Naturally, I expect that when the exception is thrown and the `CakeErrorController` is instantiated, it would generate the same view variables for me.

However, it seems that the `Controller::startupProcess()` method (which includes the call to `beforeFilter()`) never gets called on `CakeErrorController`. As I understand it, this is done by the dispatcher for regular requests, but the life-cycle of the error controller is different.

I've seen descriptions ([like this one](http://www.bradezone.com/2009/05/21/cakephp-beforefilter-and-the-error-error/)) of similar behavior in CakePHP 1.3, but of course CakePHP's error handling code has been completely overhauled in 2.0.

So either:

1. This is a bug in CakePHP's default exception handling,
2. The behavior is as intended and I just don't understand it, or
3. I'm going nuts.

I know you can't help with case 3, but if either of the first two apply, I'd appreciate input from someone who knows more than I do.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Setting the view variables in `beforeRender()` does solve my problem. However, I still wonder whether it is intentional that `beforeFilter()` never gets called on `CakeErrorController`.

Comment: +1 for "I might be crazy" self-diagnosis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the calls to `$this->set()` in the `beforeRender()` callback. That way, they'll always be set even when you throw an exception.

I had the same problem myself with some custom layout variables, as with DebugKit my page would be filled with undeclared variable warnings whenever there was any sort of error. Using `beforeRender()` instead fixed it.

Comment: +1 for an insightful answer--but I'm not sure this will work for me, since `beforeRender()` runs after the action logic. Since I'm doing authorization checks, I don't want the action logic to run if they fail.

Comment: On second thought, that doesn't make sense. Of course I can throw my exception in `beforeFilter()` and set the view variables in `beforeRender()`. I've accepted this answer since it solves my immediate problem, but I'd still like to know whether it's a bug that `beforeFilter()` isn't called on the error controller.

Answer (score 3):

you can overwrite the CakeErrorController.php by copying it to App/Controller/
and then add parent::beforeFilter() into the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly a useful option. It feels a little hackish, though. At this point I've got my code doing what it needs to do. I would still like to understand why the exception-handling process never calls `startupProcess()` on the `CakeErrorController` in the same way the dispatcher calls it on other controllers.